# Dexguard release apk not showing resource ids for elements in UI automator

Tags: android, automation, appium, android-uiautomator, dexguard

after obfuscating the apk with dexguard ,elements resource ids are not visible in uiautomator tool.

can the dexguard release build used for automation?
how to keep the elements resource ids for dexguard release build?

Answer (score 2):

`-keepresources id/**` did the trick.

Comment: @dheeraj in your app project's dexguard/proguard rule file

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I have automated many applications which have few, if any resource-id's.  Even those that do use resource-id's keep in mind that unlike in HTML they are not always unique - many elements can contain the same resource-id anyway.

If I am provided with a resource-id and I've examined the page elements closely and see that the id is unique, I'll often use it.  Elements are often more-consistently found using XPaths, in my opinion, which allows a much more detailed locator.

More often than not, I'll do something like

```
"//android.widget.TextView[@text='whatever']
```

or further:

```
"//android.widget.TextView[@text='whatever' and @index=1]"
```

Comment: But my query is that we have a native android application  which is obfuscated with dexguard. after obfuscation uiautomator is unable to see the resource ids.
we have keep the resource ids configuration in dexguard config file but still the resource ids are not visible.
have you done automation on obfucated native release apk?

Comment: @Eric Lafortune any suggestion?

Comment: I am not directly familiar with the obfuscator.  Does it hide more than the resource-id's?  The point of my answer is that you don't necessarily have to have resource-id's to form usable locators.  Or are you doing something else that requires the resource-id's?

Comment: yes we need resource ids for automation and it is native app.also dexguard is hiding all the resource ids which are also required for automation.

Comment: If you're using Appium, why are the resource-id's "required?"  Appium is capable of automating without resource-id's.

Comment: we are using resource ids to interact with elements. are you referring xpath as work around? could you please provide solution if we have to use resource ids?